# See python script running while processing a task in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Is it possible to see scripts running in Python Console - everything from tools and analysis vector to raster?

Comment: The console  it is the same thing as a classic Python shell.

Comment: If it's just to tell you where you are within your script: add a few "prints" within your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to run your python code from an IDE (for example [Wing IDE](https://wingware.com/)) as long as your python path and QGIS libraries are properly set up. An IDE will allow you to set breakpoints where the code pauses until you tell the IDE to continue the parsing. You will also be able to monitor variables in separate windows.

The below screenshot is from QGIS code run in Wing IDE. Note the breakpoint (red dot).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried pydev?
PyDev is a Python IDE for Eclipse, which may be used in Python development.

in Qgis Developer Cookbook search for "IDE settings for writing and debugging plugins"
http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/ide_debugging.html

Comment: Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. So, please try to add more explanation to your answer for helping the user to understand what you want to communicate.

Answer (score -1):

Pythontutor.com does this very well.